# Selector for img after .class and first td

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this:

```html
<tr class="row">
 <td>
  text
  <img>    <!-- Select this -->
 </td>
 <td>
  text
  <img>    <!-- Not this -->
 </td>
</tr>
```

Which CSS-only selector I could use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:first-child` pseudo-class like this:

```
tr.row td:first-child img
```